# Why am I not retrieving all service bus metrics from Azure Monitor?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-monitoring

My goal is to export the "ActiveMessages" metric for each queue/topic in my servicebus namespace for a dashboard. My current setup is as follows:

- Service bus (standard tier) with "Stream to an event hub" and "AllMetrics" enabled in diagnostics settings
- Azure function with event hub trigger that's listening to the configured event hub

This is what my function looks like:

```
    public static class MetricProcessor
    {
        [FunctionName("MetricProcessor")]
        public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("test", Connection = "AzureWebJobsEventHub")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            foreach (var eventData in events)
            {
                var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
                log.LogInformation(messageBody);
            }
        }
    }
```

The resulting message body always looks similar to the following:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "total": 1,
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 1,
      "average": 1,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:00:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingRequests",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "total": 3,
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 2,
      "average": 1.5,
      "resourceId": "removed",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:01:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingRequests",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 2,
      "total": 4,
      "minimum": 2,
      "maximum": 2,
      "average": 2,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:02:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingRequests",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:00:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "removed",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:01:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:02:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "IncomingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:00:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "OutgoingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:01:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "OutgoingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0,
      "average": 0,
      "resourceId": "-",
      "time": "2019-08-07T08:02:00.0000000Z",
      "metricName": "OutgoingMessages",
      "timeGrain": "PT1M"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why am I only getting the "IncomingRequests", "IncomingMessages" and "OutgoingMessages" metrics?

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftservicebusnamespaces) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics) documentation the metrics should be available, even though it's in preview. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are streaming events from Service bus Namespace and Not from the queue or topic itself. Try to stream events from Queues and Topics. These Incoming and Outgoing requests are from Service bus Namespace.

Comment: How would I enable those events from queues/topic subscriptions? These subresources don't seem to have the diagnostic settings like the namespace has.

Comment: Passing those metric values using Diagnostic settings is not having the option to get metrics of subresources. Have you tried to get metric data by hitting Resource url of Service bus

Comment: It will be a better way rather than relying on Diagnostic settings if you want to use those data in your custom code and HTTP client 
You can also retrieve the metric data as in this link  https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I wish these metrics could be streamed instead of pulling it from their Monitor API. If it is a limitation then it should at least be documented.

Comment: Yes, I think you can check out the last note in this article. This partially tells that we cannot stream metrics of inner entities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-overview#diagnostic-settings